# Importance of knowing GC Content of an organism

Tags: molecular-biology, genomes

I was looking at the GC content percentages of few organisms. I also know calculating the GC content percentage. But, what I want to know is, what information would we get., let us suppose if human genome has 40% of GC in the genome.

Does it help us compare the number of genes between different species, for example, a bacteria has less GC content than human, so does it mean Human produce more genes than bacteria?

or Is it that the 40% of the genome,has coding regions in them and more genes are found in those regions? What is the number "40%" actually indicate us?

Please help me understanding the concept. Would be thankful your answers and suggested reading.

EDIT: My question is what does knowing percentage of GC content help us knowing? If the GC content is 40%, does it correlate to number of genes in the genome?
Regards,
Prakki Rama.

Comment: I don't understand your question. Do you want to know the function of the different GC-contents of different genomes?

Comment: Hi, Please check my edit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Interesting question. The GC-content seems to evolve over time and it also seems that the GC-content of coding regions is higher than for the surrounding non-coding regions (see reference 1). If there is a specific function for this higher GC-content or not is (if I understand this right) debated among the groups which do research in this field. Have a look at the references (and probably also their references) to decide on this:

1. [Both selective and neutral processes drive GC content evolution in
   the human genome.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/18371205)
2. [Integrating genomics, bioinformatics, and classical genetics to
   study the effects of recombination on genome evolution.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/12082137)
3. [Recombination Drives the Evolution of GC-Content in the Human Genome](http://mbe.oxfordjournals.org/content/21/6/984.short)
4. [GC-Content Evolution in Mammalian Genomes: The Biased Gene
   Conversion Hypothesis](http://www.genetics.org/content/159/2/907.long)
5. [Contrasting GC-content dynamics across 33 mammalian genomes:
   Relationship with life-history traits and chromosome sizes](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2909565/)

Comment: Thanks for the references. So, is it that the number "40% GC content" is just a statistic to know about the organism and there is not much information associated with the number?

Comment: As far as I understand it, yes.